# Stop Skim from highlighting text and adding red dot when PDF is refreshed?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, sublime-text

When recompiling my latex file (I'm using SublimeText3), Skim highlights the place where my cursor is and creates a red dot. This is quite annoying; is there any way to stop Skim from highlighting the line and placing this red dot?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Sublime menu bar, go to Sublime Text → Preferences → Package Settings → LaTeXTools → Settings - User. This will open a document in Sublime called "LaTeXTools.sublime-settings". In the first section of the document, there is a line saying `"forward_sync": true`. Change this to say **false** instead. Then save the file and close it.

I was having this problem as well just now and this fixed the problem for me.